# Calculate hand position from upper-and lower arm's orientation

Tags: vectors, quaternions

I've got two unit quaternions in world space representing the lower- and upper arms orientation.
The lengths of upper- and lower arm are known.

**How can i calculate the hand-position relative to the shoulder from these known values?**

EDIT: I've got a Myo-armband on my upper arm which gives the following quaternions when my arm lays flat on the table and is pointing up (in order w,x,y,z)

$${arm}_{flat\ on\ table}=\begin{pmatrix}
        0.985656 \\
        0.017465 \\
        -0.049743 \\
        -0.160278 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \ \ \  
{arm}_{pointing\ up}=\begin{pmatrix}
        0.708068 \\
        -0.035339 \\
        -0.703430 \\
        -0.051269 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Comment: Do you know how to find the elbow position from this information?

Comment: No, not really. I'd create an up-facing vector with the length of my upper arm and rotate it with the upper arm quaternion and hope for the best :D

I'd assume the shoulder to be the point of origin.

Comment: You say that your quaternions represent the arm positions, but to answer this question, you (and everyone else) need to know *how* they represent them. What does "represent the arm position" mean? Are they representing rotations? If so, what vector is rotated?

Comment: The SDK of the Myo armband (which I use for the upper arm) says: `The orientation data of myo, as a Quaternion.`  
I attached the armband to my upper arm and took two example quaternions (see question).  Does that help you? If not what else can I do?

Here's a link to the Myo SDK: 
https://developer.thalmic.com/docs/api_reference/platform/classmyo_1_1_device_listener.html#adaee14d3c4f9df61899ac8aa95b6bbc6

Answer (score 2):

If you can figure out the unit vectors $V_u, V_l$ that represent your upper arm direction, and lower arm direction, and if $l_u, l_l$ are the lengths, then the vector offset of your hand from the shoulder is just $l_uV_u + l_lV_l$. But the question is, what are those two vectors? I can see two posibilities.

- There is a "Standard Vector" $n$ that is rotated by the quaternion to provide the direction of the arm. A quaternion is essentially a vector + a scalar (in fact, the terms "scalar" and "vector" were first coined to describe the real and non-real parts of quaternions), so $n$ is also a quaternion with 0 real part. So if $p_u$ is the orientation quaternion for the upper arm, then $V_u = p_unp_u^{-1}$, and similarly for $V_l$. Since the quaternion for having your arm horizontal has scalar part nearly 1, I have to assume that $n$ points in a horizontal direction. I don't know how your Myo determines its heading, though, so I can't say which horizontal direction it would be. Apparently it is close to the direction you laid out your arm, though.
- Or the orientation quaternion could directly represent the vector. If this is the case, I have no idea what the real portion represents, though. The orientation quaternions do satisfy $|p| = 1$, but that still leaves plenty of freedom left to choose different scalar components.

I have done a little searching to see I could find an answer, without success. Rreally it depends on what Thalmic decided to use. It ought to be spelled out in their documentation somewhere. Given that the whole point of this technology is to determine where the arm is directed, they should have provided the information to make use of it.

However, I have dealt with a company in the past who was so caught up in their instrumentation that it never occurred to them to specify exactly what the numbers returned meant, even after I asked very specifically. Possibly Thalmic has yet to figure out that cool measurements are useless without proper documentation.